# Why don't I pull the JVM Basic Image when i use quarkus.jib?

Tags: quarkus, jib

**Environment**:

- Quarkus version:2.4.1.Final
- maven:

  Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
  Maven home: D:\ttdl\03-software\maven\apache-maven-3.8.4
  Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd, runtime: D:\ttdl\03-software\Java\JDK11
  Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
  OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
- Java version:java11

and when run mvn clean package -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true in my win10 localhost

then error is :

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Starting container image build
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Base image 'registry-cbu.huawei.com/telcloud/jre-11:v1' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Cannot verify server at https://registry-cbu.huawei.com/v2/telcloud/jre-11/manifests/v1. Attempting again with no TLS verification.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] The base image requires auth. Trying again for registry-cbu.huawei.com/telcloud/jre-11:v1...
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Cannot verify server at https://registry-cbu.huawei.com/v2/telcloud/jre-11/manifests/v1. Attempting again with no TLS verification.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Using base image with digest: sha256:14c5d429309bb6ae92cdbe83bd8006c44e8a2370eba60c679b2374d29c370080
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Container entrypoint set to [java, -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager, -jar, quarkus-run.jar]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.807 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-14T16:36:03+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.4.1.Final:build (default) on project bill-kotlin: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor#buildFromJar threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create container image
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.containerize(JibProcessor.java:194)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.buildFromJar(JibProcessor.java:134)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:821)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, 系统找不到指定的文件。
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:566)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:547)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:88)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.StepsRunner.run(StepsRunner.java:219)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.Containerizer.run(Containerizer.java:390)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.JibContainerBuilder.containerize(JibContainerBuilder.java:598)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.containerize(JibProcessor.java:187)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, 系统找不到指定的文件。
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.docker(DockerClient.java:277)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:193)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LoadDockerStep.call(LoadDockerStep.java:74)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.StepsRunner.lambda$loadDocker$18(StepsRunner.java:618)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, 系统找不到指定的文件。
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
[ERROR]     ... 11 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and Is this error caused by the configuration of the HTTPS certificate?

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that you don't have `docker` installed locally. Is that the case?

Comment: The error message says `Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, 系统找不到指定的文件`. When I translate Chinese it says "the system can not find the file specified." For whatever reason, on your machine, you cannot run the docker CLI `docker`.

Comment: @geoand，u are right! Thansk